# Full Background on HTML DIV

Tags: html, css

When i set an image background for my div element, there is a little white space between that and my navigation bar. Also, if it is possible i was trying to try a little parallax effect with the background image. I dumbed down the code for the parts you will need. If you would like the full code, or you think i have cut something important, please let me know and i will make a link to the full code. The link is www.aaronvigal.com, and thats for all of the help in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aaron's Website</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="paralax">
<center>
    <br />
    <div class="circular"></div>
    <p class="title">Aaron's Website</p>
    <p class="subtitle">I'm Aaron. Here's my <a class="subtitle" href="index.html">website</a>! Here are my <a class="subtitle" href="index.html">photo's</a>. </p>
</center></div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <center>
            <a class="navigation2" href="index.html">|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><a class="navigation" href="index.html">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><a class="navigation2" href="index.html">|</a>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>






    body{
    margin: 0px;
}

p.title{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 0.5;
}

div.paralax{
    background: url(blur.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    moz-background-size: cover;
    o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
p.subtitle{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    color: dimgrey;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 0.5;
}
a.subtitle{
    color: darkred;
}

.circular {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(selllf.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have default margin on paragraph in header, change css to:

```
p.subtitle {
    color: dimgrey;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question on the parallax effect is, but as for the white space between the div and the nav bar, it looks like your short description under the site name is pushing it down. You have a few options that I can think of. In the css for "navigation" add a

margin-top: -15px;

Or you can make the height of the description shorter so it doesn't push it down.